# graphene-django: 'Meta.model' without either 'Meta.fields' or 'Meta.exclude' has been deprecated since 0.15.0 and is now disallowed

Tags: django, graphql, django-filter

I'm trying to return filtered results using django-graphene but it gives an error about [error-message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ibqt.png)

```
class PatientType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Patients
        exclude = ('active',)
        interfaces = (relay.Node,)


class PatientsQuery(ObjectType):
    get_patient = graphene.Field(PatientType, id=graphene.Int())
    all_patients = graphene.List(
        PatientType, first=graphene.Int(), skip=graphene.Int(), phone_no=graphene.Int()
    )
    upcoming_appointments = DjangoFilterConnectionField(PatientType)


@permissions_checker([IsAuthenticated, CheckIsOrganizationActive])
def resolve_upcoming_appointments(self, info, **kwargs) -> List:
    d = datetime.today() - timedelta(hours=1)
    settings.TIME_ZONE  # 'Asia/Karachi'
    aware_datetime = make_aware(d)
    res = Patients.objects.filter(appointments__booking_date__gte=aware_datetime,
                                  appointments__booking_date__day=aware_datetime.day,
                                  appointments__status=True)
    if res:
        return res
    return []


class Query(
    organization_schema.OrganizationQuery,
    inventory_schema.MedicineQuery,
    patient_schema.PatientsQuery,
    graphene.ObjectType,
):
    pass
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Specify the **`filter_fields`** attribute in the **`PatientType.Meta`** as

```
class PatientType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Patients
        exclude = ('active',)
        interfaces = (relay.Node,)
        filter_fields = ["field_1", "field_2"]
```

Alternatively, you can either set the **`filter_fields=[]`** or **`filterset_class`** attribute in the **`Meta`** section

More examples can be found in the doc, [**`GraphenePython- Filtering`**](https://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/filtering/)

Comment: If this is really the answer, then they need to fix their documentation because their [examples](https://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/queries/#id2) do not make mention of `filter_fields`.

Comment: I hope so :) btw, setting `filter_fields=[]` is also a valid one

Comment: Yup that's what I ended up doing.